# XMLHttpRequest does not send parameters with POST request

Tags: javascript, api, xmlhttprequest

I am using XMLHttpRequest to make a post request with JavaScript. I make the request and use the `send()` method with an x-www-form-urlencoded string as the parameter. But when this request gets made in the browser, the paramters I passed through are not sent with the request. 
**Example:** I send a post request

```
xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onload = function() {
    //code
}
xhttp.open('POST', 'https://example.com/request', true);
xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xhttp.send('lorem=ipsum&title=title');
```

So the request gets sent but instead of being sent like: `https://example.com/request?lorem=ipsum&title=title`
It sends it like this: `https://example.com/request` with none of the parameters.

Comment: IT's because you are using `POST` method, the parameters (data) is sent via request body, not header. if you need parameters be sent as part of url, then you need attach them directly into the url or use `GET` method. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/send

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the `xhttp.send()`'s parameter is the request's body, not request's  parameter.
So if the backend need parameters, the script does not send any parameters.
Move the `lorem=ipsum&title=title` to `xhttp.open('POST', 'https://example.com/request?lorem=ipsum&title=title', true);`
Should work

```js
xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onload = function() {
    //code
}
xhttp.open('POST', 'https://example.com/request?lorem=ipsum&title=title', true);
xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xhttp.send();
```